# Proof of inequality by induction, hard

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

I understand proving by induction using an equality, but when it comes to inequalities I just dont know what to do! I was wondering what I can do to solve the following question:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}  >  2(\sqrt{n+1} -1) \qquad \text{ for } n \ge 1$$

I did the base case, and I understand that I must assume this for K then prove for K+1 and use what K is equal to inside my proof for K+1. Please help I am really lost after that.

what I got :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} > 2(\sqrt{k+1} -1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Comment: Consider visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to clean up your mathematical equations.  A good first fix, enclose your math equations with dollar signs.  Next, consider using `\frac{ }{ }` to denote fractions instead of using `/`.  Finally, enclose exponents or upper limits that are more than one character in brackets.

Comment: One opening parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume for $k-1$ and then prove for $k$. Thus we need to show that $$2(\sqrt{k} - 1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \ge 2(\sqrt{k+1} - 1).$$ Subtracting 2 on both sides and multiplying by $\sqrt{k}$, we need to show $2k + 1 \ge 2(\sqrt{k^2 + k})$. Square both sides. It reduces to showing that $4k^2 + 4k + 1 \ge 4k^2 + 4k$.